# Checking a list for a value

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, T1024]
I want to check for the value 1. But if I do a ...

```
if list.__contains__(1):
```

Then I will get 1, 10, T1024. Is there a simple way of doing this. Maybe using some type of regex.
Also is performing a "contains" rather then a "for" loop much faster ?

Thanks All,

Comment: I think you've got a lot of things mixed up here. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: General advice: Don't use methods that start with underscore unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

No, you won't get that.

First, this is a list, not a dictionary.

Second, what you posted here is a SyntaxError (unless `T1024` happens to be the name of an object you previously defined).

Also, the correct idiom is

```
if 1 in mylist:
```

Finally, don't use `list` as a variable name.

---

You *would*  get the result you're seeing if you had defined the list like this:

```
mylist = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "T1024"]
```

and if you had checked for `"1"` like this:

```
for item in mylist:
    if "1" in item:
        print item
```

because the `in` operator checks for substrings when applied to a string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `in` operator to check for list membership:

```
if 1 in list:
```

Also, you should be clear on the difference between a list (what you have - an ordered collection of values) and a dictionary (an unordered collection of key-value pairs)

Answer (score 1):

what you say is a dictionary is a list, and to check for a given value in the list I would do:

```
if 1 in myList:
    doSomething
else:
    doSomethingElse
```